# Why is performance of joining tables so much faster than joining subqueries

Tags: join, subquery, psql, temp-tables

I want to join two big tables (711147 and 469519 rows). But I need just subsets of these tables (44.593 rows and 28.191 rows). When I create temp tables containing the subsets, the join is very quick (below 1 second). When I use subqueries or views, it takes 5 to 10 minutes.

The problem is, that every time when I use this query, the subset (jahr = 2016) has changed. So using the "fast way", each time using it, I would have to recreate the tmp tables first. Problem is, that this query itself is the basis of a view, and I don't know, when the view is used.

The fast way with temp tables looks like this:

```
select rechnung, art into temp rng16 from rng where jahr = 2016;
select rechnung, artikel, menge, epreis into temp fla16 from fla where jahr = 2016;
explain analyse select * from rng16 natural join fla16;
```

and the result is:

```
Merge Join  (cost=4783.18..27406.15 rows=1500012 width=104) (actual time=544.691..679.280 rows=44593 loops=1)
   Merge Cond: (rng16.rechnung = fla16.rechnung)
   ->  Sort  (cost=1681.83..1714.72 rows=13158 width=64) (actual time=222.233..233.251 rows=27630 loops=1)
         Sort Key: rng16.rechnung
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 520kB
         ->  Seq Scan on rng16  (cost=0.00..284.58 rows=13158 width=64) (actual time=0.009..2.880 rows=28191 loops=1)
   ->  Materialize  (cost=3101.35..3215.35 rows=22800 width=72) (actual time=322.449..362.445 rows=44593 loops=1)
         ->  Sort  (cost=3101.35..3158.35 rows=22800 width=72) (actual time=322.444..356.178 rows=44593 loops=1)
               Sort Key: fla16.rechnung
               Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1248kB
               ->  Seq Scan on fla16  (cost=0.00..513.00 rows=22800 width=72) (actual time=0.008..7.832 rows=44593 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 682.589 ms
```

but doing it "on the fly" with two subqueries

```
explain analyse select * from (select rechnung, art from rng where jahr=2016) rng16 natural join (select rechnung, artikel, menge, epreis from fla where jahr = 2016) fla16;
```

lasts for ages. Output of explain is:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..10.98 rows=1 width=21) (actual time=0.036..453240.711 rows=44593 loops=1)
   Join Filter: (rng.rechnung = fla.rechnung)
   Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1257076670
   ->  Index Scan using rng_jahr on rng  (cost=0.42..5.51 rows=1 width=9) (actual time=0.017..54.372 rows=28191 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (jahr = 2016)
   ->  Index Scan using fla_jahr on fla  (cost=0.42..5.46 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=0.020..9.875 rows=44593 loops=28191)
         Index Cond: (jahr = 2016)
 Total runtime: 453253.579 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using subqueries, try joining tables, like here:

```
explain analyse 

select 
    rng16.rechnung, rng16.art 
    fla.rechnung, fla.artikel, fla.menge, flaepreis
from 
    rng rng16 
natural join 
    fla
where 
    rng16.jahr = 2016
    and fla.jahr = 2016
```

Is it still a nested loop?

Comment: Yes it still is a nested loop. The response is too long for one comment, so I split it in two comments:

Comment: <code>    Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..10.99 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.036..440478.942 rows=44489 loops=1)
   Join Filter: ((rng16.rechnung = fla.rechnung) AND (rng16.lager = fla.lager) AND (rng16.monat = fla.monat))
   Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1257076774     </code>

Comment: <code>   ->  Index Scan using rng_jahr on rng rng16  (cost=0.42..5.51 rows=1 width=15) (actual time=0.017..50.585 rows=28191 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (jahr = 2016)
   ->  Index Scan using fla_jahr on fla  (cost=0.42..5.46 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=0.019..9.856 rows=44593 loops=28191)
         Index Cond: (jahr = 2016)
 Total runtime: 440490.148 ms
</code>